# Mongodb indexing

Tags: mongodb

I have a query

```
db.messages.find({'headers.Date':{'$gt': new Date(2001,3,1)}},{'headers.From':1, _id:0}).sort({'headers.From':1})
```

I have set `headers.From` as index. Now which part of query will use this index ? i.e find part of query or sort part of query?

Explain output is

```
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor headers.From_1",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 83057,
    "nscannedObjects" : 120477,
    "nscanned" : 120477,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 120581,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 120581,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 250,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "headers.From" : [
            [
                {
                    "$minElement" : 1
                },
                {
                    "$maxElement" : 1
                }
            ]
        ]
    },
    "server" : "Andrews-iMac.local:27017"
}
```

Any help is appreciated !!!

Comment: The query doesn't include anything that is indexed, just `headers.Date`. It should be using the index for the sort, but as your query doesn't use an index, it's already done a huge amount of work. You might want to create a compound index of `headers.Date` and `headers.From`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index is being used for the sort part, not for the query, as your query doesn't use the headers.From field and your sort does.

Comment: Thanks lucia... headers.From is used in find query also

Comment: No, you are using it to project it (the second parameter of find) but not for search, so it is not in the query. db.collection.find(query, projection) from http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/